# Hiding a Anchor Tags with a specific url

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am Implementing Webview in android application... I want to hide a Specific  tag like with a specific href how can i do this...

Example: i want to hide Link 2 and Link 4 which has tracklist in href tag with href="/track.php?id=icmo" how  to ? as their is no class or id for  tag

```
<p class="track">
  <font color="maroon"> … </font>
  <a href="/track.php?id=ycmo"> Link 1 </a>
<span style="color:#339900;"> … </span>
</p>

<p class="track">
  <font color="maroon"> … </font>
  <a href="/tracklist.php?id=icmo"> Link 2</a>
<span style="color:#339900;"> … </span>
</p>

<p class="track">
  <font color="maroon"> … </font>
  <a href="/track.php?id=kcmo"> Link 3 </a>
<span style="color:#339900;"> … </span>
</p>

<p class="track">
  <font color="maroon"> … </font>
  <a href="/tracklist.php?id=mcmo"> Link 4 </a>
<span style="color:#339900;"> … </span>
</p>

<p class="track">
  <font color="maroon"> … </font>
  <a href="/track.php?id=mcmo"> Link 5 </a>
<span style="color:#339900;"> … </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Did you mean the third and fifth element? As in counting from 0? Since the second element and the fourth have a "/tracklist.php?id"... url but they both have different url ids, the [2] link says icmo and the [4] says mcmo, how do you wan't to filter? what do you know in advance since i can only guess what you wanted if your question and your code are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

> href="/track.php?id=icmo"

doesn't match any of the elements you describe you wan't to remove, i'll assumme is a typo, but since i'm not sure if you know before hand which url and id combination you want to hide i'll give you an option with the exact string match using indexOf and a regex version using a pattern, this might not be the exact pattern that you need but might point you on the right direction.

Only the if clause changes and the filter var used

**indexOf Version**

```
var links, i, href, filter
filter = 'track.php?id=';
links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
  href = links[i].href;
  if(href.indexOf(filter) !== -1){
        links[i].style.display = 'none'
  }      
}
```

**Regex Version**

```
var links, i, href, regexFilter
regexFilter = /track.php\?id=+(k|m)/;
links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
  href = links[i].href;
  if( href.match(regexFilter) ){
        links[i].style.display = 'none'
   }       
}
```

**[Here is a jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ba7qg/1/)**

Comment: suggestion: use `querySelectiorAll` for complex queries only.. old `getElementsByTagName('a')` gives better performance..

Answer (score 2):

Using [jQuery Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("a[href*='tracklist']").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use simple CSS for this.

```
a[href="/track.php?id=icmo"]
{
    property: value;
}
```

As for the property and value, you can use `display: none;`for the browser to render it as if it wasn't there or you can use `visibility: hidden;` so that the anchors will be hidden but space will still be allocated for them.

For my source and for more examples, you can visit w3schools.com which is where I read about various web languages *(incl. CSS)*.